# Magento 2 : Elastic search Data fetch

Tags: magento2, product, gift-card, product-type

I am using below script to fetch data from Elastic search, I want to know how the data is being fetched from Magento to ES.

This script get me product details in Output, but for some product the data is incorrect i need to check for it. **I am not sure from where product is being pass to ES, so please advise me or let me know how it works actually.**

```
require_once '../mageless/api_bootstrap.php';

$app = new LightApi();
$app->setOutput([]);

$currentEnv = 'prod';
$currentSite = 11;
$pid = preg_replace('[^0-9,]', '', $_GET['pid']);
$productIds = array_diff(array_map('intval', explode(',', $pid)), [0])
$index = 'magento2_product_11_v14';
$host = 'localhost:9200';
$query = [
    'query' => [
        'ids' => [
          'values' => $productIds
        ]
    ]
];

$ch = curl_init('http://' . $host . '/' . $index . '/_search?pretty');
echo 'http://' . $host . '/' . $index . '/_search?pretty'; exit;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     json_encode($query));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($result, TRUE);
```

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 3):

Product data builder that sends to Elasticsearch is (vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Model/Adapter/BatchDataMapper/ProductDataMapper.php):

> Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\BatchDataMapper\ProductDataMapper

Open that class and check the **map** method.

```
public function map(array $documentData, $storeId, array $context = [])
{
    $documents = [];

    foreach ($documentData as $productId => $indexData) {
        $this->builder->addField('store_id', $storeId);
        $productIndexData = $this->convertToProductData($productId, $indexData, $storeId);
        foreach ($productIndexData as $attributeCode => $value) {
            // Prepare processing attribute info
            if (strpos($attributeCode, '_value') !== false) {
                $this->builder->addField($attributeCode, $value);
                continue;
            }

            $this->builder->addField(
                $this->fieldMapper->getFieldName(
                    $attributeCode,
                    $context
                ),
                $value
            );
        }
        $documents[$productId] = $this->builder->build();
    }

    $productIds = array_keys($documentData);
    foreach ($this->additionalFieldsProvider->getFields($productIds, $storeId) as $productId => $fields) {
        $documents[$productId] = array_merge_recursive(
            $documents[$productId],
            $this->builder->addFields($fields)->build()
        );
    }

    return $documents;
}
```

If you print the $documents then you can see the data that you send to Elasticsearch.

Comment: How to test this ?
I have created a script which has the code which i had mentioned in script.
So when i run that script it output product data.
if i add print_r and exit in file Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\BatchDataMapper\ProductDataMapper
then it can be tested with the script ?

Comment: Magento sends products data to ES during indexing. So, You need to run "bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext" for checking data.

Comment: ok & print_r & exit will work there ?
and data will be seen in terminal ?

Comment: Maybe, never tried. You can log that data and check from log file.

Comment: I have added a log just before return $documents; & executed bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext

Comment: From where does this map method is called in magento code ?

Comment: The issue is i am getting name twice such as [name] => chain smoker set chain smoker set in log for product.

Comment: Create a Plugin and modify that.

Comment: But i am not sure why it save name twice, it sets name of config & simple both.
can you tell me where it sets the name ?
& any way to fix it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127840/discussion-between-newdeveloper-and-sohel-rana).